# Difference between 2 styles of closing file in Python

Tags: python

Can somebody please explain the difference between the following?

```
handler = open(printFile, "w")        
handler.close()
```

and

```
handler = open(printFile, "w")   
close(printFile)
```

Comment: I'd check your source files for a definition of `close()`.

Comment: Where did you get that `close` standalone function (case 2)? It is definitely not a builtin in Python 2.7 (not in 3.2 either).

Comment: Don't forget `with open(someFile, 'w') as handler:` which is probably what you want to be doing instead of calling close explicitly http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is pretty simple: **The latter does not exist.**

If it does in your application, it's user-defined and might just call `firstArgument.close()` or do something else such as killing your dog.